# Ruby on Rails Convention over Configuration (CoC) Issues to scale Large Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, naming-conventions, ruby-on-rails-5

Working with Ruby on Rails for somewhile now. I'm enjoying it's builtin "Convention over Configuration" for small project. But, I'm little anxious about CoC application in Large Rails Projects.

I know some pre built-in configuration raises more difficulty than ease, when need to scale the application in broad.

**What is those all specific Configurations will raise problem for me to scale? I will very grateful, if you please briefly explain those issues?**

Comment: Have a look at this http://trailblazer.to/

Comment: That's a very broad question and cannot be briefed... i can assure you that there are tons of huge apps using rails and their problems are more of maintain ability and readability with better mature design patterns in place like service objects and method objects rather than scalability and performance http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Comment: @mad_raz, Thanks. I know some SOF post, which large and also some of them are wiki. Hoping someone elaborate the answer than one already.

Answer (score 2):

Convention over Configuration is more of a problem with estimates and prediction than scaling. Sometimes it just seems like everything is easy and all of a sudden, you will spend a lot of time on something that you thought was a 5 minute work. But all of this is actually a learning problem. Once you get proficient enough with Rails, the would be no danger anymore.

Concerning scaling, Convention over Configuration is not a problem at all. The problem here is that Rails is a strongly opinionated framework. If you do it the Rails way, Rails helps you. If not, Rails sometimes stand in your way. A few examples:

- RESTful routes and controllers - what if your routes and controllers cannot be designed as RESTful resources?
- Strict ORM mapping - what if you can't actually easily map database tables to objects and you'd rather work with joined data?
- Other than usual CRUD pages, unconventional single page applications, wizards, etc.